# How to copy a Corba struct (containing an "any" type) into a C++ struct

Tags: c++, sqlite, struct, corba

In Corba, I have a struct like so:

```
module XYZ {
    typedef string AttributeName;  
    struct AttributeColumn {
        AttributeName name;              // Column attribute name
        any    data;                     // Column attribute value
    };
    typedef sequence <AttributeColumn> AttributeTable;
}
```

It contains values from a corresponding Sqlite database table which has the following field:

```
ABC_Name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

I want to copy these values into a C++ struct, which consists of the following:

```
namespace DEF {
    typedef std::string AttributeName;
    typedef std::vector<std::string> StringCol;
    struct AttributeColumn {
        AttributeName name;              // Column attribute name
        StringCol str;                   // Column values if string
    };
   typedef std::vector<AttributeColumn> AttributeTable;
}
```

Here is my attempt:

```
XYZ::AttributeTable & xyz_table = getAttributeTable (); // This gives me the table containing the data from the database.
int rows = getLength ( xyz_table ); // This gives me the number of rows in the database.
DEF::AttributeTable def_table;

for (int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
    def_table[i].name = xyz_table[i].name;
    std::cout << def_table[i].name << std::endl;
    xyz_table[i].data >>= def_table[i].str;
    std::cout << def_table[i].str << std::endl;
}
```

However, the above does not compile.
I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: 1> error: no match for ‘operator>>=’ (operand types are ‘CORBA::Any’ and ‘DEF::StringCol’ {aka ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’})
```

If I comment out the last two lines in the for loop, then the code compiles, but it crashes.
So, somehow, the copy into the def_table for the "name" field does not work correctly either.

Comment: Which CORBA implementation are you using? Have you tried TAOX11?

Comment: Hi, I don't know anything about the CORBA implementation. The only element of CORBA I have access to is the .idl file, which I am not able to modify. How could I discover what implementation is used by that file ?

Comment: Which IDL compiler are you using to compile the IDL file, that IDL compiler is related to your CORBA implementation.

Comment: Also you have to link with some CORBA libraries which are provided by your CORBA implementation. Maybe the CORBA Programmers Guide at https://www.remedy.nl/opensource/corbapg.html is a good start

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
namespace DEF {
typedef std::string AttributeName;
typedef std::vector<std::string> StringCol;
struct AttributeColumn {
    AttributeName name;              // Column attribute name
    CORBA::Any str;                   // Column values if string
};
typedef std::vector<AttributeColumn> AttributeTable;
};
```

because str need to be the same type of data .